# Is there a relationship between printf %p format and basic_ostream format?

Tags: c++, format, printf, ostream

As far as I know %p used in printf [writes an implementation defined character sequence defining a pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

But is it always supposed to write the same character sequence than

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value );
```

?

I have not found any information concerning a potential relationship between the two formats and in many cases the character sequence look to be the same, but is it guaranteed, or both formats for pointers can be independently implementation defined with different character sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::basic_ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for pointers uses [`std::num_put::put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put), which is defined to work the same as [`std::printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) with `%p` plus locale-specific conversion and padding.